# How can I work out if an a tag in a div was selected?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using JQuery, how can I work out if one of the a tags in my div with the id of "nav" was selected so that I can clear out the contents of my other div named "body-wrapper"? I am doing this so that I can change the contents of the div depending on the selection in the navigation menu.

My code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qvjnc/

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just have a click event that clears out the content to start and then inserts the content you want.  Example:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
   $('#body-wrapper').html('<b>whatever i want</b>');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

To display different content based on the item clicked change it to something like this:

```
$('#work').click(function(){
   $('#body-wrapper').html('<b>this is work</b>');
});
$('#about').click(function(){
   $('#body-wrapper').html('<b>this is about me</b>');
});
```

you would have to give your anchors ids in this example.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I differentiate the text in the #nav a so if it's Work, I can display work, or if it's About, I can display the about contents?

Comment: Thanks, I am just using `onclick = function()...` for each div instead.